# How do I make a visit counter that displays an image for every visit the web page has had? Creating a collage of images

Tags: php, image

Basically, I am creating a digital art project.

For this I am aiming to get a webpage to show how many visits its had by displaying an image for every visit. So basically every time someone visits or refreshes the web page a new image will appear; 50 visits = 50 images and so on. I want the images to be taken from a folder on the server at random. I have code for a basic visit counter, but it only works for sessions. I need to edit this code so that for every visit a random image appears. Apparently it should be fairly simple but I am very new to php and am still learning a lot.

This is the code I have for the visit counter:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
  $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
else
  $_SESSION['views']=1
echo "Page views: ".$_SESSION['views'];
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated :)
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant by: `I want the images to ....`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to somehow persist the number of visits on the server, using a solution like a database server or a key-value store. For example, you could install [Redis](http://redis.io/) on the server, install a Redis client such as [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis), then for each visit have the script run something like:

```
$redis = new Predis\Client();
$redis->incr('views');
```

Then, when you want to know how many total views you had, you can use:

```
$views = $redis->get('views');
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a .txt file to store the number, do this:

```
<?php $pageCount = ("count.txt");
$number = file($pageCount);
$number[0] ++; 
$open = fopen($pageCount,"w");
fputs($open ,"$number[0]"); 
fclose($open); echo $number[0]; ?>
```

Now, all the visits are added to the count.txt you can now add the second part to open the number of images. I am on my phone, so I am unable to test the next part done, but this link might help: http://chrisvall.com/coding/php-how-to-get-a-random-image-to-display-from-a-specific-folder
Now, the next part would use $number as the number and do a for loop until all the images are  echoed onto the page.
I hope this helps